# CSS текст по центру, а ссылка - справа

Tags: css, веб-программирование, css-grid

Хей! Как можно красиво и правильно сделать так, чтобы текст `<h1>` был в центре, а картинка, которая помещена в `<a>`, была справа? Это все должно находиться в `<header>`
[image: header]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте жёсткую ширину для `<a>` и используйте выравнивание текста по центу для `<h1>`.
Но тогда текст в `<h1>` сместиться влево на ширину `<a>`, тогда компенсируйте это `padding-left: *ширина <a>*`.

Пример:

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 50px;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header > * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

header > h1 {
  padding-left: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>TEXT</h1>
  <a href="#">#</a>
</header>
```